# Appium - Java Action Check

Tags: java, selenium, image-processing, appium

I'm working on a test script that works with Appium (Selenium) on Java for mobile devices.
In the script, there's following codes:

```
 _driver2.swipe(startXL, startYL, endXL, endYL, 100);
```

and

```
_driver2.tap(1, startX, startY, 100);
```

These methods swipe a game object or click on a button in a game.

Here are some details:
Swiping method is using absolute locations on screen. Tap method is using a location that is calculated by an image recognition function.

Here's my question:
While the test is running; if device's screen is different than expected, like push notifications or native dialogs, test doesn't stop and still tries to find an image/location and then clicks/swipes.

I want to make it stop if there's a different screen than expected or the game object didn't move.

My question is probably not clear but I can give you details comment by comment.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an simple if else condition

> If element is found { Swipe  }

Else  { Perform other action  }

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using 'element finder', I'm using image recognition and specific locations.

Comment: U can use the image locator instead of element

Comment: Code will be like if image found {script for swipe  }

Comment: That's the problem. I'm using OpenCV and it always finds a match, there're no controls for it, or I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Step 1:
    public boolean isElementFound(String element)
        {
            try{
            WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
            System.out.println("isElementFound : true :"+element);
        }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.println("isElementFound : false :"+element);
            return false;
        }
    Step 2 : while(isElementFound(String element))
             {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
            System.out.println(startx+" "+starty);
            System.out.println("Entering swipe");

                System.out.println("Swipe from "+startx +" " +starty +"to" +endx +" " +endy );
                touchAction.press(startx, starty).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endx,endy).release().perform();


 //   WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));
            webElement.click();

             }
```